# If I Add the item on the recyclerview the item add duplicate

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

First time, If I add the item(click the send button) on the recyclerview, it does successfully,

but
if I add the item second time, I expect see the item 1,2 but 1,2,1,2 add to the recyclerview

I'm using the multiViewType RecyclerView and the viewmodel

and I also use the databinding on the adapter code

Thank you for your help

below it's my code

```
private val commentList = mutableListOf<Comment>()
private var chatAdpater = ChatAdapter()
....

binding.sendBtn.setOnClickListener {
                postChat()
            }

.....

private fun postChat(){
    chatViewModel.postReChatResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

        val newCommentList = mutableListOf<Comment>()
        commentList.add(
              Comment(
                nickname,
                description,
                writeTime,
                boardId.toInt(),
                categoryId.toInt(),
                id,
                images,
                2,
                commentsid.toInt(),
                0,
                null
               )
              )

         newCommentList.addAll(commentList)
         chatAdpater.setData(newCommentList,commentList.size-1)
   }
}


---------adapter-------

.....

var commentList:MutableList<Comment>? = mutableListOf()

.....

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setData(commentList: MutableList<Comment>,position: Int){
        this.commentList = commentList
        notifyItemInserted(position)
    }

class ViewHolder(val binding: ChatItemListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun onBind(data: Comment) {
            binding.comment = data
        }
    }

    class ReViewHolder(val bindingTwo: ReChatItemListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindingTwo.root) {
        fun onBind(data: Comment) {
            bindingTwo.reComment = data
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (commentList!![position].isrecomment) {
            1 -> 1
            else -> 2
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val binding =
            ChatItemListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        val bindingRe =
            ReChatItemListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return when (viewType) {
            1 -> ReViewHolder(bindingRe)
            else -> ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int{
        return commentList?.size ?: 0
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (commentList?.get(position)?.isrecomment) {
            1 -> (holder as ReViewHolder).apply {
                holder.onBind(commentList!![position])
                 }
            2 -> (holder as ViewHolder).apply {
                holder.onBind(commentList!![position])
                holder.binding.chatText.setOnClickListener {
       
                 }
              }
           }
```

Comment: Hi, What is the purpose of the chatViewModel.postReChatResponse.observe ?

Comment: with Retrofit I post the user's chat to the server and then I add the user's chat to the recyclerview
I fix the name of the postReChatResponse to postChatResponse sorry for confusing

Comment: It is not clear why you are calling the "observe" method on every click of the "send button". Usually observe should be called once. Can you share you ViewModel code?

Comment: I'm practice the viewmodel now, so I'm not good at this sorry..

`private val _postChatResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<String>> = 
MutableLiveData()

val postChatResponse: LiveData<Response<String>>
        get() = _postChatResponse

 fun postChat(hashMap: HashMap<String, Any>) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = chatRepository.postChat(hashMap)
                _postChatResponse.value = response
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("postChatError", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: oh I can solve this problem thankyou I delete the postChat() function on the btn Click Thankyou So much

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing just use single comment list and add value to the list and then use notifyDataSetChanged for adapter. this will works. Here you are adding values to the list again and again so that is why it is repeating data.